# End-of-file command in JSON HTTP POST request from putty

Tags: json, http, post, putty, eof

It is merely a childish question, but I have stuck upon an HTTP POST request through putty command line. After performing the initial request:

```
~$ POST <url:port/directory>
Please enter content (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) to be POSTed:
...(content posted there)
```

I have no option to send the command, since the only keyboard sequence working is CTRL-Z, which stops the procedure, other than sending the command. Is there any other interaction for the END-OF-FILE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL-D will simulate EOF. You can also pipe into POST, which may make things easier for testing, for example:

```
cat ~/my-json-file.json | POST <url:port/directory>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, it was really what I needed to get unstuck from the situation. I couldn't find the EOF anywhere on the web and it seemed so weird. Apparently, it was one of the few combinations I hadn't tried! Thank you again!